# After upgrading to Rails 3.1.1: "undefined method `javascript_expansions'" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

Ive upgraded rails from 3.0.10 to 3.1.1 and now Im getting the following Error:

`undefined method 'javascript_expansions' for ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper:Module`

but not on every page, just some pages are involved. I googled it already but I didnt find anything! Im running ruby 1.9.2 by the way...

Also my asset pipeline doesnt seem to work. Its not loading the `application.css`and `application.js` file even its in the `assets` subfolders. Im getting a routing error each time I try to fetch any of the files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem adding the `therubyracer` gem to the `Gemfile` and runned `bundle install`. Thats it...

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same error, after removing tinymce and running bundle install everything was running smooth, so heat up the coffee machine and try to remove suspect JavaScripts.

Maybe it was just a lucky shoot he he