# undefined method `javascript_expansions' for ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, activescaffold

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [After upgrading to Rails 3.1.1: “undefined method `javascript_expansions'” error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8138368/after-upgrading-to-rails-3-1-1-undefined-method-javascript-expansions-error)

I'm using `tinymce` with `activescaffold` in `rails 3.2` and I'm getting this error:

```
undefined method `javascript_expansions' for ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper:Module
```